# Dynamically changing nodes in MongoDB ReplicaSet

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using mongodb with it's native driver in javascript.

You connect to a replicaset by specifying what nodes are in the set:

```
var mainReplSet = new MongoDB.ReplSet([ 
                new MongoDB.Server( '0.0.0.0, 27017, { auto_reconnect: true } ),
                new MongoDB.Server( '0.0.0.0', 27017, { auto_reconnect: true } ),
                new MongoDB.Server( '0.0.0.0', 27017, { auto_reconnect: true } )
            ], { rs_name:'ReplicaSetName', readPreference: MongoDB.ReadPreference.NEAREST } );
```

So if I dynamically add a node to this set, I need to update all scripts that connect to the replica set. Therefore restarting whatever server it's running on. Is there anyway to include new nodes without having to update this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to update your scripts upon adding (and conditionally removing) members . What you need is to supply a seed list. Basically you can supply a single one, but this is not recommended as it may be down at that time.

Quorum servers should be sufficient even if you have more members in your replica set. So for your three members set, two servers are enough.

Each member holds it's own copy of the set configuration object and knows who the master is. It's not even mandatory to specify the master in the seed list.

[Have a look here](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/connect-driver-to-replica-set/)

Comment: What about when you're writing to the database? For write preference you can specify how many nodes the data propagates to before returning. This is set in getLastErrorDefaults in mongo shell, or it can be set in script. Is there anyway to just set the "w" to "all" instead of "majority"? Otherwise I'll have to update the script for any server that writes to the DB

Comment: There's no such option as setting w to "all". You can achieve this by setting w=X where X is number of data node replicas. However this is far from being recommended for being very slow and risky (some of your replicas being in a non active state). You can easily set a write concern which guarantees write to all or most of your data centers using [tag sets](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/#replica-set-configuration-tag-sets)